# Laravel upgrade from 5.8 to laravel 6 - Call to undefined method Laravel\Cashier\Cashier::useCurrency()

Tags: laravel, upgrade, laravel-cashier

I've just tried to upgrade from laravel 5.8 to laravel 6.

Run `composer update` and got the following error in the console:

```
 Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Call to undefined method Laravel\Cashier\Cashier::useCurrency()

 at C:\wamp\www\laravel\my-project\app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php:34
  30|         Paginator::useBootstrapThree();
  31| 
  32|         Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.stripe.secret'));
  33| 
> 34|         Cashier::useCurrency('gbp', '£');
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to consult [the upgrade guide](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/10.0/UPGRADE.md) for Cashier.

> The `useCurrency` method has been replaced by a configuration option in the new Cashier configuration file and the `usesCurrency` method has been removed.

There are a variety of significant changes in Cashier v10.

Answer (score 3):

removed the following from AppServiceProvider.php

```
Cashier::useCurrency('gbp', '£');
```

added the following to env file:

```
CASHIER_CURRENCY=gbp
CASHIER_CURRENCY_LOCALE=en_GB
```